# How would I install a different copy of linux on a old laptop?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, software-installation, uninstall

TLDR; I am trying to install a GUI version of Linux on an old laptop with Ubuntu Server already installed, but get a grub error when I boot. How can I  get past this problem.

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.

Entering rescue mode...
```

Current Linux Version: Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS

New OS: Linux Mint 21.2 64 bit (disk image on USB)

I installed Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS on my old laptop.

The intention was to back up all my photos onto a home server.

Now, I want to install a Desktop version of Linux on it.

I have tried to research and ask some some friends, but I am just not knowledgeable enough about the subject to understand.

What can I do/investigate to move forward? Please treat me like a 7 year old, when I see 'grub' I think of an insect in the ground.

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to install the packages needed to run a graphical desktop? It seems needlessly complicated to try to install a new system on top of the old one, while at the same time trying to not remove old important data (photos).

Answer (score 0):

The bootable USB isn't created correctly, you can create a bootable USB through the `mkusb`  utility (GUI and command line).

[Ubuntu help:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

> `dus-iso2usb` (command line)

> This makes a system that can boot via grub into an iso file both in UEFI mode and BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode), 'grub-n-iso'.